# Import Facebook SDK to Android

Tags: android, facebook, import, sdk

After import facebook sdk to my dependencies as:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
```

and set up all of facebook requisites on manifest. It started to crash on build.

On Gradle console shows:

```
    * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

After some hours looking for solutions I added bolts library as a solution but it didn't work.

And the worst, when I rebuild the project on Android Studio the Build is a Success if I run the project to a device it fails.

Any tips?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021901/android-studio-gradle-build-fails-execution-failed-for-task-dexdebug

Comment: and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787747/android-studio-errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug

Comment: finally http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864609/execution-failed-for-taskappdexdebug

Comment: sorry, but this error may have various causes

Comment: After all, thanks! I checked one by one of my dependencies and if I delete the facebook import everything works fine. maybe I'll download the facebook .jar and import it manually.